# PHP Post not getting information back

Tags: php, html, netbeans

I'm just learning about html and php but it doesn't work. Could anyone point me in the right direction:

My form:

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
                    <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
                    <p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
You are <?php echo (int) $_POST['age']; ?> years old.
```

When I click submit the page loads to the same page but it doesn't pick up either name or email.

I've also tried adding:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

But when I click submit it brings up a 404 error with:

```
<?php%20echo%20htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[
```

in the last bit of my URL?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: is your file saved `.php` ?

Comment: In addition is PHP running, apache running, etc...

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the comments.
My file is .php
I have wamp running and when I check the apache modules it says php_5 ticked.

I tried running phpinfo() but it litrally brings back that. I'm at a loss

Answer (score 0):

PHP:
`Hi <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>.
You are <?php echo $_POST['age']; ?> years old.`

In input type of age write:
`<input type='number' ....`